# Ho to put a new line in <p> tag in my jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have text like this generated from flask with query

> Predictions: Apple Cedar rust - 99.646: Cedar apple rust is a fungal
>   disease caused by Gymnosporangium juniperi-virginianae that requires
>   juniper plants to

Now I wanted to put this into 2 lines like this

> Predictions: Apple Cedar rust - 99.646
>
> Cedar apple rust is a fungal disease caused by Gymnosporangium
>   juniperi-virginianae that requires juniper plants to

Here is my jquery code that generated above output.

```
var new_data = JSON.parse(data.payload);
           $('#result').append('Predictions: ');
           for (var i in new_data){
             var _html = `
               <p>${new_data[i].name}: ${new_data[i].val}</p>
             `
              $('#result').append(_html);
           }
```

I tried to do this but didn't work.

```
<p>${new_data[i].name}: "<br />" ${new_data[i].val}</p>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
var _html = "<p>" + ${new_data[i].name}: ${new_data[i].val} + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<p>
  <span style="display:block">${new_data[i].name}:</span> ${new_data[i].val} 
</p>
```